# How to access 3rd table from 1st table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, laravel

i'm gonna to access my 3rd table form 1st .
 my tables design already in below :

**1st Table** : User

- id **(PK)**
- name
- email
- password

**2nd Table** : User_Role

- id **(PK)**
- user_id **(foreign)**
- role_id **(foreign)**

**3rd Table** : Roles

- id **(PK)**
- authority
- title

My User Model class code is :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    public function user_role()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(UserRole::class)->withTimestamps();
    }


}
```

And My User_Role model class is :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserRole extends Model
{

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

now how can i access to my 2nd tbl filed for example :

```
$user =  User::find(Auth::id());
return $user->user_role->first()->id;
```

and how can i access to my **3rd** tbl filed ??

title from **Roles Table** ??

is my **table's relations** correct ??

Comment: You should define your Roles model, instead of the User_Role model. Please let me write an answer below

Comment: Make a model for the Third table , Role, not Roles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your User model, you should define its relationship with Role, not with user_role.

In your User model:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'user_role');
}
```

Then in Role model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_role');
}
```

Laravel will assume the pivot table for n:m relationship to be "user_role". So you don't need to specify the table name, although you can (as shown above).

To get first user Role, you just do:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->roles->first();
```

Comment: Thank You Very much

Comment: @MohammadaliMirhamed my pleasure!